# .NET WebBrowser Control fails to open Printer Dialog box intermittently when trying to print

Tags: c#, .net, printing, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

I have a .NET WebForms app running on about 100 Windows Server 2008 R2 servers which contains the WebBrowser Control.
When trying to print the webpage by right-clicking in the webpage, the printer dialog box fails to display. This only happens intermittently.
This issue started after we upgraded from IE8 to IE10.

Server Specs:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
- Citrix XenApp 6.5
- Internet Explorer 10 (Tried using IE11, same issue exists)
- About 20-30 print drivers installed.

What I have tried so far:

- Wrote a standalone app with WebForms and WebBrowser Control, and I am able to replicate this on the server.
- Running this app on my workstation works without any issues.
- Rebooted server.
- Tried upgrading from IE10 to IE11, but the same issue exists.

This is my simple Web Browser App

```
private void FormWebBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried clearing the `cache` when the web page renders and restarting IIS and then trying it

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache, and no change. Restarting IIS is not really an option because its not just a single site that is having this issue. It is multiple sites. Even sites like yahoo.com or google.com.